# Django update context processor variable using ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have items variable in my context processor to count cart items and display on page. How is it possible to do it with ajax? and update number of cart items when user adds new item?

context_processors.py

```
def ToyCartItems(request):    
    try:
        user_cart = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
        cart_items = user_cart.cart_item.all()

    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart_items = 0
    return {'NumberOfItems': cart_items}
```

Comment: You're not thinking about this in the right terms. Ajax doesn't care about context processors; the result of this context processor is a place on a page where you've output the number of items in HTML. It's that HTML element that you need to update with your Ajax.

Comment: I want to update html element which is located in nav.html and i include it in my base.html. nav.html Doesn't have view. I get NumberOfItems variable from context_processor

Comment: Your context_processors is ok. You only need to recharge the page.
Or actualize the number via ajax in template.